# How to install the perl DateTime module under CentOS8. yum install "perl(DateTime)" worked in CentOS7 but not in 8

Tags: perl, perl-module, centos8

There are some Perl modules that could previously be installed with:
    yum install "perl(DateTime)"
Under CentOS7. In CentOS8 I get the error:

```
No match for argument: perl(DateTime)
```

I have the same problem for perl(Template), perl(YAML::XS), perl(Crypt::Eksblowfish::Bcrypt) and perl(JSON::XS)

I tried searching with:

```
yum provides *DateTime*
```

But I can't find anything there either.

Comment: Whatever happened with `perl-DateTime`?  On CentOS7 (and before) those were names for the packages for Perl modules -- does this not work anymore?

Comment: @zdim `perl(Module::Name)` is the syntax for what modules a perl package in RH distros provide. dnf/yum accept it directly and look up in `provides` when it doesn't match a package name.

Comment: It's possible that these simply have not been packaged for RHEL/CentOS 8 yet.

Comment: Looking at http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8/BaseOS/x86_64/os/Packages/ it appears this is the case.

Comment: Try install it with `cpanm`, i.e.  `sudo cpanm Date::Time`. I tested this in a docker container for CentOS8 and it installed `Date::Time` to `/usr/local/share/perl5`

Comment: @HåkonHægland Date::Time is a very different unrelated module.

Comment: @Grinnz Thanks, I missed that.

Comment: @Grinnz `sudo cpanm DateTime` also works fine in my container. It just takes more time to install than `Date::Time` :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`perl-DateTime` is no longer part of the CentOS 8 base OS. You'll need to enable the [`PowerTools` repository](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8/PowerTools/x86_64/os/Packages/), i.e. as root

```
# yum config-manager --set-enabled PowerTools
# yum update
# yum repolist
repo id                     repo name                                     status
...
PowerTools                  CentOS-8 - PowerTools                         ...
...

# yum install "perl(DateTime)"

or...

# yum install perl-DateTime
```

`perl(YAML::XS)` (AKA `perl-YAML-LibYAML`) should also be available.

`perl(Template)` (AKA `perl-Template-Toolkit`) and `perl(Crypt::Eksblowfish::Bcrypt)` (AKA `perl-Crypt-Eksblowfish`) no longer seem to be provided, not even in EPEL8. So you'll have to install them from CPAN.

Comment: Interestingly, I had to call it with repository name lowercase:
yum config-manager --set-enabled powertools

Comment: I can confirm that I had to call it with lowercase as well